# Showing Div on Hover over img (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using CSS I am running into trouble getting a div later on the page to show up using the hover command over an img tag. I'm writing the page using Bootstrap 3 - Any idea why this may be a problem? The words in "hovershow" appear at the right spot on the page when they are not originally hiden using CSS which makes me think there's a problem with the command itself.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <img id="Email_Logo" class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="img/Email_Icon_Send1.jpg" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="hovershow"><p>This should show on hover</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hovershow{
    display:none;
}

#Email_Logo:hover .hovershow{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: with your case you can't because in css you can't select parent, you can change your `Email_logo` and move it a step up and use the `~` sibling selector and select the child

Answer (score 3):

That's definitely not how CSS works.

The following CSS implies there is an element `.hovershow` somewhere within `#Email_Logo`:

```
.#Email_Logo:hover .hovershow{
    display: block;
}
```

And well... that's not the case. What you want can either be achieved by some easy Javascripting or a change in your HTML 'tree' and CSS.

Comment: Is it possible to show a div on hover for a non-child element?

Comment: with css no you can do it with js

Comment: @user2512696 Not in CSS. CSS doesn't have selectors for parent/previous elements